# HTML buttons working everywhere with the exception of the Android app

Tags: android, ajax, codeigniter, http, browser

I recently finished styding and started my apprenticeship in a company where my first project consisted in fixing a web made in CodeIgniter. The problem is that once I was finished solving errors and everything seemed fine, I realized that it only works properly on every browser, iOS but in Andorid there are two buttons that do not.

Since I could not grasp the problem, I decided to made all the web https in order to avoid possible CORS erros blocking my ajax calls, but it didn't work.

Then I saw that the apk url was http too, so I remade it with https and giving the permission for internet as well as storage (This was because one of the buttons stores the information you provide in the form and keeps written every time you come back to that page). All of this wouldn't work neither.

So now I have a web who is fully functional, an iOS app which works fine too but an Android one where two of its buttons dont work.

I doubt it comes from incompabilities with jQuery or the ajax calls, because the other buttons and functions are working.

Thank you all for your time and patience. If my question is not well formulated ill change whatever is necessary.

What I added in AndroidManifes.xml:

```
<!-- Internet permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Storage permission  -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The buttons both go to this function, where depending on the action to take (save data form the form / signing in the user into the db) one of boths functions is executed:

```
function tomarAccion(tipo) {
  fiorentina.showIndicator();
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: base_url + tipo,
      data: datosUsuario,
      success: function(datos)
      {
          fiorentina.hideIndicator();
          tratarResultado(datos);
      }, 
      error: function(datos)
      {
          fiorentina.hideIndicator();
          fiorentina.alert('Se ha producido un error al conectar con el servidor. Por favor, pruebe en unos minutos.');
      }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Minimize the description of the specific problem only.

Comment: give website url and exact location of button which is not working in screen . I will check if problem is in android or not.

Comment: I'll take your comment into account @Danish, thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much too @Ankit, would you mind telling me how can you tell if it is coming from the Android?

This is the exact url, the buttons are the ones below
https://lafiorentina.es/#!/backend/acceso/perfil

Comment: This error is coming in android :- "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080", source: https://lafiorentina.es/js/framework7.js (7046).
Try resolving this at server side.
I will recommend connect app with chrome developer browser , it will show correct error which is coming , try resolving it there and it is easy to connect via android studio.